# Can't reset PRAM and reinstall OS!

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, snow-leopard, nvram

I have a problem with my MacBook Pro 2010 13 inch, 2.4 GHz. Originally I had Snow Leopard installed on my Mac, then I was trying to upgrade it to Lion (official version from App Store).

During the installation, an error occurred and I got a kernel panic. But that's not exactly the problem. I found out that the laptop had had a firmware password set by somebody (not me).

None of the boot modifier keys (except option) appear to work. When I press option, it asks me for a password. Some people told me to switch the RAM slots or take one out and then turn on the computer holding <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. That didn't work either. Still see the password prompt.

Any ideas how to reset it?

Comment: You should explain what is currently working. Can you still boot on Snow Leopard OS?

Comment: No.nothing is working. the only thing I can do is to turn the computer on and then there's a  grey screen with kernel panic message. installation CD is not seen, i suggest because of that firmware password

Comment: Try running AHT (Apple Hardware Test) by holding "D" while booting. btw, have you upgraded/changed the ram?

Comment: Alice: May I ask who set the firmware password in the first place?
@mspasov the AHT resides in /System/LibraryCoreServices/.diagnostics , so re-installing Mac OS probably deleted it.

Comment: I think that Alice has also lost her internet connection 2 hours later...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is too late of an answer. I know you've already attempted to disable the password, but try these steps exactly:

You can remove the firmware password by changing the RAM configuration, booting up to the startup menu, shutting down and changing it back. Basically, if you have two 1GB chips of RAM in there now, you can remove one of the chips, start up holding alt/option, shut down and put the other chip back in. This will remove the firmware password.

Now, you can follow [these](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3910?viewlocale=en_US) instructions for doing the erase and install.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Matt's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/36919/11791) should apply to a 2010 MacBook Pro but it won't work for newer machines.

*[MacBook Air (Late 2010) and later, MacBook Pro (Early 2011) and later, iMac (Mid 2011) and later, Mac mini (Mid 2011): Recovering a lost firmware password](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3554)*

> Only Apple retail stores or Apple Authorized Service Providers can unlock these computers protected by a firmware password.